# How to find all orthogonal matrices which commute with a given symmetric matrix?

Tags: matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

Suppose we have a symmetric matrix $H$. I'd like to find all the orthogonal matrices $S_i$, which commute with it. Particularly I'm interested in the set of $S_i$, which are linearly independent from the others in the set.

Currently to find the first such matrix I just minimize the difference $SH-HS$ with the constraint that $SS^T=I$. But even for not too large matrices like $16\times16$ this takes quite a lot of time to minimize it.

Are there any efficient numerical procedures to find these matrices?

Comment: What do you mean "all" the orthogonal matrices which commute with it? How are you parameterizing this space of orthogonal matrices?

Comment: @VictorLiu for example, I have a set of already found ones, and want to get "next" one, i.e. any other matrix not already found. After finding it, append it to the set of already found ones and repeat. And so on, until there're no more such matrices.

Comment: There are uncountably infinite such $S$. There is no notion of "next". See my answer below for one such parameterization.

Comment: The set of solutions changes dramatically when some of the eigenvalues become equal. Are they well spaced, the eigenvalues? This seems to be a numerical problem, rather than theoretical.

Comment: @orangeskid the matrix $H$ may (and in most cases will) have degenerate spectrum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ Ruslan , you ask (I am not sure !) for orthogonal matrices $(S_i)$ that are linearly independent, orthogonal and s.t. $S_iH=HS_i$. We may assume that $H=diag(\lambda_1I_{n_1},\cdots,\lambda_kI_{n_k})$ where the $(\lambda_i)$ are real distinct and $n_1+\cdots +n_k=n$. Then $SH=HS$ iff $S=diag(U_1,\cdots,U_k)$ where $U_i$ is orthogonal. We reduce the problem to choose linearly independent elements in $O(n)$.

Note that $\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\-1&0&0\\0&0&-1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0&2&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$. Then the pseudo-permutation matrices (and consequently $O(n)$) span $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ and we can choose $n^2$ linearly independent pseudo-permutation matrices. I think that you can find explicitly such a system of matrices for every $n$ ; it is your business.

EDIT. Answer to Ruslan. 1. The $S_i$ are pseudo-permutations  (entries are $\pm 1$).

2. among the previous matrices, you can choose $n^2$ that are linearly independent. Now you must find such a model for each value of $n$. For instance, if $n=2$, then you can take $\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: So, as I understand you, by assuming $H=\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1I_{n_1},\cdots,\lambda_kI_{n_k})$ you mean to switch to eigenbasis of $H$, and $n_k$ would be multiplicities of eigenvalues. Then $S$ would be a block-diagonal permutation matrix, permuting the identical eigenvalues between each other, and all such block-diagonal matrices will form the set of $S_i$. Do I understand you right?

Answer (score 2):

Since $H$ is symmetric (and I'm assuming it has real entries as well), then by the spectral theorem, $H$ can be orthogonally diagonalized; i.e. it has an orthogonal set of eigenvectors such that $H = Q\Lambda Q^T$ where the columns of $Q$ are eigenvectors of $H$ and $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix of the corresponding eigenvalues of $H$. The commutator is then
$$ SQ\Lambda Q^T-Q\Lambda Q^TS $$
If you let $S = QM Q^T$ for a diagonal matrix $M$, then the commutator is identically zero. This is from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commuting_matrices). I'm not sure this represents *all* the possible $S$ (as in, I'm not sure if the diagonal entries of $M$ completely parameterize the space of valid $S$, or how you would show that).

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting. Actually I forgot to say that I'm looking for linearly independent matrices $S$. Then there should be a finite number of them.

Comment: What does it mean to you for two matrices to be linearly independent?

Comment: I mean the set $K$ of linearly independent matrices, i.e. of such matrices $S_i\in K$ that for all $i$, $S_i$ is not a linear combination of matrices $S_j$, $j\ne i$.

Comment: BTW, won't $QMQ^T$ be symmetric, not orthogonal?

Comment: Yes, $QMQ^T$ will be symmetric. So, in the original question, you are looking for a set of $S$ which are mutually orthogonal, and each $S$ should also be orthogonal? It seems like in that case, the only solution is the identity matrix.

Comment: I intended $S$ to be orthogonal, and every $S_i$ to be linearly independent from the others.

Comment: The only possibility is the identity matrix then. You can't even have a diagonal matrix of $+1$'s and $-1$'s because you're scaling rows on one side and columns on the other. If you have a counterexample to my statement for a $2\times 2$ or $3\times 3$ sized $H$, I'd love to see it.

Comment: There may be non-identity solutions. E.g. for a circulant matrix $M$ there can be shuffling matrices $S$.

Comment: If that is the case, you need to provide more details on what structure or prior knowledge is known about $H$. Otherwise, for general $H$, you can't solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to solve first for $H$ block diagonal, with the blocks on the diagonal scalar matrices.
If you can solve it for this case, you can in general.